# Batch file setting double quote a variable

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

In a Windows XP .bat file, how do I set a variable value to use double quote? I couldn't find special characters for batch file.

```
SET myVariable= " \"myValue \" "
```

Comment: On what platform? What kind of "batch file"?

Comment: On Windows XP and just a regular cmd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is for Windows, you need to escape the double quotes with a caret (`^`):

```
set myVariable=^"myVlaue^"
```

Putting single quotes around the value won't work, the value will include the single and double quotes.

Comment: You should accept Andriy M's response as the answer as it's more accurate than mine.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the method @Patrick Cuff has offered or you can do it quite simply:

```
SET var="Value"
```

Let's see if it works...

```
ECHO %var%
```

and the output is:

```
"Value"
```

Yes! :)

Comment: If it was a snake, it would have bit me.

Comment: To do the reverse, e.g. for filenames that you don't want to include the quotes, you can surround the **entire parameter** of the `set` command in double quotes like this `SET "mydir=C:\files\some path"` so then you can follow up with `SET "myfile=my own file.txt"` ... therefore when you put them together `echo hi > "%mydir%\%myfile"` the quotes will surround the whole path and file, and will not be included in either component.  It will expand to `echo hi > "C:\files\some path\my own file.txt"` where the quotes surround the whole thing so it works with the spaces in the path and filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SET myVariable='"myValue"'
```